how create decorator without creating metadata in nest js?
i want to create middleware as decorator in nest js.
but problem is i dont want to create metadata.
and i have only one question how wrong is my solution ?
can i use it normally ?
export function Permission(required_permission: string) {
  @Injectable()
  class PermissionClass implements CanActivate {
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
      const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      // LOGIC ... if something throw new Unauthorized...
      return true;
    }
  }

  return applyDecorators(UseGuards(PermissionClass));
};

this is how use this decorator
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}
  @Get()
  @Permission("users:read")
  isWorking(): string {
    return this.appService.isWorking();
  }
}

Expectations:
better solution or confirmation
